# como puedo agregar un parametro a una url ya existente en angular

Tags: angular, url, parametros

Tengo un formulario con paginacion. cuando hago la consulta al api con los parámetros que el usuario selecciona del formulario, la respuesta me viene con el enlace a la siguiente pagina, pero a este enlace debo agregarle otro parámetro que no me esta devolviendo y es obligatorio, como podría hacer para que en el botón de paginacion "Pagina Siguiente" o "Pagina Anterior" usar esa misma URL pero agregar un nuevo parámetro (ese que necesito) ? he visto que lo mas parecido es usar

```html
queryParamsHandling: 'merge' }
```

pero en los pocos ejemplos que he encontrado veo que solo colocan esa linea de codigo y no ponen el parámetro que quieren agregar a la URL, no creo que es lo que sirve para lo que quiero lograr. como podría hacer eso ?  Alguien con experiencia podría ayudarme? gracias de antemano al que pueda ayudarme.

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy amplia. Con cada cambio de paginación, el parámetro es diferente? Es el mismo? Tu lo calculas? O el usuario debe ingresarlo?

Comment: el parametro que quiero agregar siempre es el mismo.

Comment: El parametro tu ya lo tienes desde la primera paginación?

Comment: logre resolverlo de la siguiente manera: Cree un objeto, que tiene todos los parámetros que le paso a esa vista y en ese objeto agrego el otro parámetro que necesito y se lo paso a la petición POST. no sera la mejor manera, pero fue lo que me ocurrio. Una pregunta amigo... sabras como puedo mantener los datos del filtro actualizado? me refiero a que tengo un filtro, lleno los campos y le doy a "buscar" se muestra la vista con los resultados, pero como haría para que si el usuario hace click en el navegador para retroceder, se actualice el filtro con los valores que tenia anteriormente?

Comment: Bien que pudiste solucionarlo. Acerca de tu pregunta: Lo puedes hacer usando los parámetros y escuchando a los cambios en el `ActivatedRoute`. Pero mejor esa es una pregunta diferente. Hazla aparte y con gusto te muestro en detalle en una respuesta.

Comment: como hago para avisarte cuando haga la pregunta, para que me ayudes?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97604/discussion-between-nery-ortez-and-julianprog).

Comment: soy nuevo en StackOverflow, como me comunico contigo por Chat?

Comment: Postea la pregunta y después deja un mensaje aquí... Yo recibiré la notificación y buscaré la pregunta en tu perfil.